# make lua method that can directly change arguments

Tags: methods, lua, auto-increment, pass-by-reference, meta-method

How to create a method like `string.gsub(...)` in lua ?

I want my function can change Arguments that I pass them to the function.

I know that string and number Type Variables pass by name ( CALL BY VALUE ) in functions,

but I don't know how gsub can change ( apply directly in string type variable ) when we try to use it like `s:gsub(...)` the `s` variable change and affected by `gsub(...)` method !

I want to create a method `Inc(...)` that when I use it like `ex:Inc()` the ex ( number var )
Increment by 1 !!!

Help me implement this ... I want that ex variable ( example : ex = 1 ) be numerical (not table)

```
ex = 1
ex:Inc()
print(ex) -- ex == 2
```

Thank you .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`s:gsub(...)` does *not* affect `s`, except when you do `s=s:gsub(...)`. Try this:

```
s="hello"
print(s:gsub("[aeio]","-"))
print(s)
```

In Lua, all arguments are passed by value. There is no way to change the value of a variable from within a function. (You can change the contents of a table, but not the table itself.)

Comment: cannot force pass a variable by reference ? like & op in c++
accessing the address of variables in memory ! or get help from meta-tables ?  in act I want to overload ++ op in lua , but it seems impossible !

Comment: @NIMIX3 No, there is no `pass by reference` in Lua.